# Unity Animations List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good day!

There is a list of animations:

[Anim1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndWJB.png)

When using this code, only the first one in the list scrolls:

[Anim2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzvUD.png)

How can I refer to MenuHide (also known as Element1)?

When using this code, it gives an error:

[Anim3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NStxy.png)

[Anim4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEENc.png)

Comment: Could it be that u are looking for "HideMenu" and not "MenuHide"?

Comment: Can you please show the whole code? I especially want to see how you setup `public GameObject HideMenu;` . Also, can you tell what's your main goal? Do you want to just play one animation at one time, and another at another time? If that's the case, this is not the preferred way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Solution found.

```
public void PlayAnimation(string animationName) {    
 foreach(AnimationState state in First) {
    if (state.name == animationName) {
        First.Play(state.name);      
        break;
    }
 }
 }

 PlayAnimation("MenuHide");
```

Then mark our animation as shown here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/animationclip-must-be-marked-as-legacy.213952/#post-1494616

https://answers.unity.com/questions/577801/animation-must-be-marked-as-legacy.html

Everything worked right for me. 
I hope this helps someone. Sorry for me English. Thanks to everyone and especially [Sergey Mishin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/199253/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD) from Stackoverflow RU